# Anyway to block certain droppable objects

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-draggable, kendo-droptarget

For example if I have `object1`, `object2` and `object3`
These can only be dropped in `Zone1`

Then I have `object4`, `object5` and `object6`
These can only be dropped in `Zone2`

How could I configure this?

Also I would like `object7` to be allowed to drop in either `Zone1` or `Zone2` but not `Zone3`

At the moment I have the following configured.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".draggable").each(function (index, item)
        {
            $(item).kendoDraggable({
                filter: ".handle",
                hint: function () {
                    return $('#box').clone().css("display", "block");
                },
                dragstart: draggableOnDragStart,
                dragend: draggableOnDragEnd
            });
        });

        $("#droptarget").kendoDropTarget({
            drop: droptargetOnDrop
        });

        $("#droptargetGauges").kendoDropTargetArea({
            filter: ".test1, .test2",
            drop: droptargetOnDrop
        });
    });
```

but this means that any `div` with the class `draggable` can either be dropped in `droptarget` or `droptargetGauges`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`group`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/droptarget#configuration-group) configuration option, which is available for both `DropTarget` and `DropTargetArea`:

HTML:

```
<div id='dragoptions'>
    <div class="draggable dragoption" id="person-one">person one</div>
    <div class="draggable dragoption" id="person-two">person two</div>
    <div class="draggable dragoption2" id="person-three">person three</div>
    <div class="draggable dragoption2" id="person-four">person four</div>
    <div class="draggable dragoption3" id="person-five">person five</div>
</div>
<div id="targets">
    <div class="droptarget type1" id="target1">role a</div>
    <div class="droptarget type1" id="target2">role b</div>
    <div class="droptarget type2" id="target3">role c</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#dragoptions").kendoDraggable({
    filter: ".dragoption",
    group: "roles",
    hint: function (element) {
        return $(element).clone();
    },
    dragstart: draggableOnDragStart,
    dragend: draggableOnDragEnd
});

$("#dragoptions").kendoDraggable({
    filter: ".dragoption2",
    group: "roles2",
    hint: function (element) {
        return $(element).clone();
    },
    dragstart: draggableOnDragStart,
    dragend: draggableOnDragEnd
});

$("#dragoptions").kendoDraggable({
    filter: ".dragoption3",
    group: "both",
    hint: function (element) {
        return $(element).clone();
    },
    dragstart: draggableOnDragStart,
    dragend: draggableOnDragEnd
}); 

$("#target1").kendoDropTarget({
    group: "roles",
    dragenter: droptargetOnDragEnter,
    dragleave: droptargetOnDragLeave,
    drop: onDrop
});

$("#target2").kendoDropTarget({
    group: "roles2",
    dragenter: droptargetOnDragEnter,
    dragleave: droptargetOnDragLeave,
    drop: onDrop
});

$("#targets").kendoDropTargetArea({
    group: "both",
    dragenter: droptargetOnDragEnter,
    dragleave: droptargetOnDragLeave,
    filter: "#target1, #target2",
    drop: onDrop
});

function draggableOnDragStart(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass("dragging");
}

function draggableOnDragEnd(e) {
    $(".draggable").removeClass("dragging");
}

function droptargetOnDragEnter(e) {
    $(e.dropTarget).addClass("drop");
}

function droptargetOnDragLeave(e) {
    $(".droptarget").removeClass("drop");
}

function onDrop(e) {
    $(".droptarget").removeClass("drop");
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/5B5uP/)